# Ajax dependant dropdownlist using mysqli and html select tags, return value even when select tags are not closed

Tags: php, ajax, drop-down-menu

i am having a problem in which the code that i wrote are working as the way I wanted when there is 2 dependant drop down but when i want to add a third dependant dropdown i realize that my code had gone wrong on the select tag (the select tag are not closed), But it works??

I dont understand why my codes work when the select tag is not closed, but my codes dont work when the select tag is closed @ line 43

```
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

function getState(val) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index.php",
    data:'country_id='+val,
    success: function(data){
        $("#state-list").html(data);
    }
    });
} 

</script>

</head>

<?php 

$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "dropdowndb");

if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    echo $conn->connect_error;
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM country";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
?>

<select onChange="getState(this.value);">
<?php while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) { ?>
    <option value="<?= $row[0] ?>"><?= $row[1] ?></option> 
<?php } ?>
</select>   

<select name="state" id="state-list">
    <option value="">Select State</option>    

<?php if(!empty($_POST["country_id"])): ?>

    <?php
        $query ="SELECT * FROM state WHERE country_id = '" . $_POST["country_id"] . "'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    ?>
    <select>
    <?php while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) { ?>
        <option value="<?= $row[0] ?>"><?= $row[1] ?></option> 
    <?php } ?>
    </select>   

<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: PHP does not care about the HTNL and  the browser fixes the bad HTML as best as it can. BUT what does not work exactly? Looks like you try to shove an entire HTML page into a select element.

Comment: how many select's you have in your code ?